Is there a better way to approach this database tree structure using Entity Framework 7.0 code first
I am developing a database using c# with Entity Framework 7.0 Code First.  I have come across a scenario that's a little tricky for me. Consider the following entity diagram.


A Store has many Pods
A Store has many Positions
A Pod has many Positions

The diagram becomes a tree structure.  This has the unfortunate effect of Foreign Key redundancy in the Positions table. It also makes navigation classes awkward. My Position class looks like this
public class Position
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(StoreId))] 
    public virtual Store Store { get; set; }
    public int StoreId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(PodId))]
    public virtual Pod Pod { get; set; }
    public int? PodId { get; set; }
}

The above scenario exists quite happily in the real world. A Store does indeed contain many Pods and / or many Positions. A Pod can also contain many Positions.  I'm just wondering how some of you more experienced folks might approach this?

Please look at the tag descriptions. I assume you must retag to ef-core tags.

The following entities works for your relationship. No need to explicit configure the foreignkey or other modelbuilder settings.
    public class Store
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Pod> Pods { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Position> Positions { get; set; }
    }

    public class Pod
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Position> Positions { get; set; }
    }
    public class Position
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

